# Double inheritance run-time error in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm having a run-time error when running my project which contains the following classes:
`Shape` - abstract
`Polygon :public Shape` - abstract
`Triangle :public Polygon` - normal class

I've created a `vector<Shape*> shapes` and when I'm trying in my code do:

```
shapes[i] = new Triangle(****);
```

I'm having run-time error.
Is it has something to do with the double inheritance or is it a problem in my code?
Since I've also go a class `Circle :public Shape` and when doing

```
shapes[i] = new Circle(*****);
```

it all works fine..

**edit:**
it is `vector<Shape*> shapes;` as most of you guessed.
 I do not go out of the voctor's boundries
I've changed it to `.push_back(new Circle())` and it still just collapse.

The run-time error I get doesn't show any error code, it just shuts the exe file.

Shape is definetly abstract since all my methods are *pure virtual*
so as Polygon.
I've made my own constructors(in Shape and Polygon) but they do nothing, just blank scope to prevent problem with the default constructor.

**Shape.h**

```
#include "Point.h"

    class Shape  
    {  
    public:  
        Shape();  

        //Methods
        virtual double get_Perimeter() = 0; //Returns shape's perimeter
        virtual double get_Area() = 0; //Returns shape's area
        virtual void move(point p) = 0; //Moves the shape
    };
```

**Shape.cpp**

```
#include "Shape.h"

shape :: Shape()
{
}
```

**Polygon.h**

```
#include "Point.h"
#include "Shape.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Polygon :public Shape
{
protected:
    //Fields
    vector<point> points; //Vector of the polygon's points

public:
    //Constructors
    Polygon();


    //Methods
    virtual int getNumOfPoints() = 0; //Returns number of points
    virtual vector<double> get_Sides() = 0; //Returns vector of side's length
    virtual vector<point> get_Points() = 0; //Returns vector of points

    virtual double get_Perimeter() = 0; //Returns shape's perimeter
    virtual double get_Area() = 0; //Returns shape's area
    virtual void move(point p) = 0; //Moves the shape
};
```

**Polygon.h**

```
#include "polygon.h"
polygon :: polygon()
{
}
```

**Point.h**

```
class point
{
protected:
    //Fields
    double x; //the X value of point
    double y; //the Y value of point

public:
    //Constructors
    point(double x, double y); //Creates new point with given params
    point(const point &other); //Creates new point with other point's params

    //Methods
    double get_X() const; //Returns X field
    double get_Y() const; //Returns Y field
    void move(int dx, int dy); //Adds given params to current params
    void move(point p); //Adds p's params to current params
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
vector<shape*> shapes;

    //Creating new tirangle
    point* p1 = new point(1,1);
    point* p2 = new point(5,1);
    point* p3 = new point(3,4);
    shapes.push_back(new triangle(*p1,*p2,*p3));
```

**Triangle.h**

```
#include "point.h"
#include "polygon.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class triangle :public polygon
{

public:
    //Constructors
    triangle(point p1, point p2, point p3); //Creates new triangle with given params
    triangle(const triangle &other); //Copies other's params to new triangle

    //Methods
    point get_P1() const; //Returns p1
    point get_P2() const; //Returns p2
    point get_P3() const; //Returns p3

    int getNumOfPoints(); //Returns number of points
    vector<double> get_Sides(); //Returns vector of side's length
    vector<point> get_Points(); //Returns vector of points

    double get_Perimeter(); //Returns shape's perimeter
    double get_Area(); //Returns shape's area
    void move(point p); //Moves the shape
};
```

**Triangle.cpp**

```
#include "triangle.h"
#include <cmath>

    //Constructors
    triangle :: triangle(point p1, point p2, point p3)
    {
        points[0] = p1;
        points[1] = p2;
        points[2] = p3;

    }
    triangle :: triangle(const triangle &other)
    {
        points[0] = other.get_P1();
        points[1] = other.get_P2();
        points[2] = other.get_P3();
    }

    //Methods
    point triangle :: get_P1() const
    {
        return points[0];
    }
    point triangle :: get_P2() const
    {
        return points[1];
    }
    point triangle :: get_P3() const
    {
        return points[2];
    }

    int triangle :: getNumOfPoints()
    {
        return points.size();
    }
    vector<double> triangle :: get_Sides()
    {
        vector<double> sides;
        sides[0] = sqrt(pow(points[0].get_X()-points[1].get_X(),2)+pow(points[0].get_Y()-points[1].get_Y(),2));
        sides[1] = sqrt(pow(points[1].get_X()-points[2].get_X(),2)+pow(points[1].get_Y()-points[2].get_Y(),2));
        sides[2] = sqrt(pow(points[2].get_X()-points[0].get_X(),2)+pow(points[2].get_Y()-points[0].get_Y(),2));
        return sides;
    }
    vector<point> triangle :: get_Points()
    {
        return points;
    }

    double triangle :: get_Perimeter()
    {
        vector<double> sides = this->get_Sides();
        return sides[0]+sides[1]+sides[2];
    }
    double triangle ::get_Area() //By Heron's Formula
    {
        vector<double> sides = this->get_Sides();
        double area = this->get_Perimeter()/2;
        double tmp = area;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            area*=(tmp-sides[i]);
        return sqrt(area);

    }
    void triangle :: move(point p)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            points[i].move(p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should create a vector<Shape*>

Comment: What run-time error are you getting?

Comment: I'm suspicious whether this even compiles. Since `Shape` is abstract, it doesn't meet the container requirements.

Comment: If `Shape` really were abstract, then `vector<Shape> shapes;` wouldn't compile. Presumably, you actually have a `vector<Shape*>`, since your examples put pointers into it. Could you show us some real code; preferably a self-contained program that reproduces the error you're seeing.

Comment: yes it is vector<Shape*> shapes, forgot to mention it in the post.

Answer (score 3):

A vector can only store objects of identical type. What you need is a container of owning *pointers*:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes;

shapes.emplace_back(new Triangle);
shapes.emplace_back(new Circle);
```

Answer (score 0):

basically what Kerres said.
Just an additional note which might be relevant in similar cases.

If your `Shape` class were not abstract and you used

```
std::vector<Shape> shapes;
```

then this

```
shapes[i] = Circle(***);
```

would be valid, but your object would get sliced! Which means, all information in the further derived classes are lost. This is an important fact to remember!

Comment: I don't think this would even compile, because `Shape` is abstract and thus doesn't meet the container requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the constructor of `triangle`:

```
triangle :: triangle(point p1, point p2, point p3)
{
    points[0] = p1;
    points[1] = p2;
    points[2] = p3;
}
```

This attempts to write to elements of an empty vector; you can only use `[]` to access vector elements if the vector is large enough. You should use `push_back()` to grow the vector:

```
points.push_back(p1);
points.push_back(p2);
points.push_back(p3);
```

or, if you can use C++11, assign from an initialiser list:

```
points = {p1, p2, p3};
```

Likewise for the copy constructor; although there's no point declaring a copy constructor at all since the implicitly-generated one will correctly copy the vector of points.

Veering slightly off-topic, be very careful if you're using a container of raw pointers to manage object lifetimes: it's very easy to accidentally remove a pointer without deleting the object, leaking memory. I'd suggest using smart pointers.

There's also another potential problem: `Shape` doesn't have a virtual destructor, which means you can't delete any of the shapes in your vector; doing so could cause a crash. You should one:

```
virtual ~Shape() {}
```

Comment: @Ehunter: In that case there's something wrong with the code you haven't posted, and my crystal ball needs recharging. If you could tell us exactly what the error is, and perhaps post a small program that reproduces it, then we might be able to help.

Comment: @Ehunter: Also, the constructors for `point`. (By the way, you shouldn't need your own copy constructor - the implicitly generated one should be fine. Likewise, there's no need to define empty default constructors for most of these types).

Comment: I had to make the empty constructors since it did some problems.
And I've posted the codes for Triangle.

Comment: @Ehunter: I've found the problem in `triangle`'s constructors, and updated the answer.

Comment: I've changed it as you suggested, but it still crashes..  
The odd part is it just crashes, even when debugging there is no error code, nothing..